# AutoMapper - Map when destination has a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper

I am trying to use AutoMapper to map the Domain model to Dtos in ASP.NET Core Web API.

Domain class

```cs
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CategoryDiscount { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Domain Product Class

```cs
public partial class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

DTO class

```cs
public class GetCategoryProductsDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int CategoryDiscount { get; set; }

    public List<ProductDto> Products {  get; set; }                  

}
```

Mapper Configuration

```cs
CreateMap<Category, GetCategoryProductsDto>();
```

Everything works fine however I wanted to calculate the product price after deducting the Category Discount.

[image]

Comment: Any library that we use in the project should simplify the life and reduce the amount of code. AutoMapper complicates development and increases the amount of code. The best way out is not to use it.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1: With `.AfterMap()`**

To perform the `Price` calculation after mapping, you can use [`.AfterMap()`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html#before-and-after-map-action).

```cs
CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>();
CreateMap<Category, GetCategoryProductsDto>()
        .AfterMap((src,dest) => 
        {
            dest.Products.ForEach(x => x.Price -= src.CategoryDiscount);
        });
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ .NET Fidde](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FRoTW7)

---

**Solution 2: With Custom Value Resolver**

As @Lucian suggested, a [custom value resolver](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html) is another option to handle the `Price` calculation.

```cs
CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Price, 
                    opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, member, context) => src.Price - src.Category.CategoryDiscount));

CreateMap<Category, GetCategoryProductsDto>();
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UhkKlc)

Comment: A resolver for `Price` would work better, as `Product` has a reference to `Category`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Good suggestion, added into the answer for another option. =)